# Full calender in codeigniter doesn't show the date

Tags: json, echo

sorry might be this is common issue but for me hard to digging on it, let me quick !

i have been working on calender date which show employee got cuti(free permission) and i took the tutorial from [here](http://fullcalendar.io/js/fullcalendar-2.6.0/demos/basic-views.html) then i'm trying to change it with my condition

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset='utf-8' />
<link href='<?php echo base_url()?>assets/fullcalender/fullcalendar.css' rel='stylesheet' />
<link href='<?php echo base_url()?>assets/fullcalender/fullcalendar.print.css' rel='stylesheet' media='print' />
<script src='<?php echo base_url()?>assets/fullcalender/lib/moment.min.js'></script>
<script src='<?php echo base_url()?>assets/fullcalender/lib/jquery.min.js'></script>
<script src='<?php echo base_url()?>assets/fullcalender/fullcalendar.min.js'></script>
<script>

    $(document).ready(function() {

        $('#calendar').fullCalendar({
            header: {
                left: 'prev,next today',
                center: 'title',
                right: 'month,basicWeek,basicDay'
            },
            defaultDate: '2016-01-12',
            editable: true,
            eventLimit: true, // allow "more" link when too many events
            events: "<?php echo site_url('login/date');?>"
            /*
            events: [
                {
                    title: 'All Day Event',
                    start: '2016-01-01'
                },
                {
                    title: 'Long Event',
                    start: '2016-01-07',
                    end: '2016-01-10'
                },
                {
                    id: 999,
                    title: 'Repeating Event',
                    start: '2016-01-09T16:00:00'
                },
                {
                    id: 999,
                    title: 'Repeating Event',
                    start: '2016-01-16T16:00:00'
                },
                {
                    title: 'Conference',
                    start: '2016-01-11',
                    end: '2016-01-13'
                },
                {
                    title: 'Meeting',
                    start: '2016-01-12T10:30:00',
                    end: '2016-01-12T12:30:00'
                },
                {
                    title: 'Lunch',
                    start: '2016-01-12T12:00:00'
                },
                {
                    title: 'Meeting',
                    start: '2016-01-12T14:30:00'
                },
                {
                    title: 'Happy Hour',
                    start: '2016-01-12T17:30:00'
                },
                {
                    title: 'Dinner',
                    start: '2016-01-12T20:00:00'
                },
                {
                    title: 'Birthday Party',
                    start: '2016-01-13T07:00:00'
                },
                {
                    title: 'Click for Google',
                    url: 'http://google.com/',
                    start: '2016-01-28'
                }
            ]

            */
        });

    });

</script>
<style>

    body {
        margin: 40px 10px;
        padding: 0;
        font-family: "Lucida Grande",Helvetica,Arial,Verdana,sans-serif;
        font-size: 14px;
    }

    #calendar {
        max-width: 900px;
        margin: 0 auto;
    }

</style>
</head>
<body>

    <div id='calendar'></div>

</body>
</html>
```

Please see i make comment in events then make events to get data in database
this is the the results events

[image]

Then this is the final calender doesn't show anything, 
[image]

what do i miss in my code !

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#calendar').fullCalendar({
        header: {
            left: 'prev,next today',
            center: 'title',
            right: 'month,basicWeek,basicDay'
        },
        //defaultDate: '2016-01-12',
        editable: true,
        eventLimit: true, // allow "more" link when too many events
        events: "<?php echo site_url('login/date');?>",
    });
});
```

I don't know why when i make comment in datedefault it give me the results calender, hope someone in the future can help

Comment: Nothing missing just move to next month. Your events are of February month and you are in January month.

Answer (score 0):

Nothing missing. All your events are for February month and you are on January month that's why you can't see anything in January calendar.

```
[{title: '2', start: '2016-02-12'}, { title: '3', start: '2016-02-13' }]
```

Just click on next month, you will see your events in February month.

Comment: Oh cool, how do you know it ! is it problem make comment there Chintan ? Thanks

Comment: When you set default date, it points to that date. And when you comment then it will get machine's current date.